# How to use mongoose on NestJS

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongoose, nestjs

I import MongooseModule and use it according the documentation of NestJS and when I compile the server locally I get this error `node_modules/mongoose/index.d.ts:1883:33 - error TS2339: Property 'Buffer' does not exist on type 'typeof globalThis'`. I installed `@types/node` but I don't know what to do from here.

app.module.ts

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { ClientsModule } from './clients/clients.module';
import { MongooseModule } from '@nestjs/mongoose';

@Module({
  imports: [ClientsModule, MongooseModule.forRoot(`mongodb+srv://xxx:xxx@cluster0.ikjjp.mongodb.net/yyyyyyyy?retryWrites=true&w=majority`)],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem by running `npm i @types/node@15.14.1`. After that, I could run the server. For anyone having this issue in a near future, try both solutions from Karunakaran and mine.

Answer (score 1):

Explicitly add '@types/node' by installing types. Should be fixed in mongoose, but works as of now.

```
npm i --save-dev @types/node@^14.0.0
```

Comment: I forgot completely about this question. I solved this issue and will post what worked for me. Basically I did what you said.

Comment: Is this `@types/node@^14.0.0` compatible with `@nestjs/common^7.0.0`?